# actionscriptタグの追加を提案します

Tags: 討議, タグ

[EventListnerの挙動は、サーバに置いた場合と、直接htmlを叩いた場合とで違いがあるのでしょうか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/6550/8000)

この質問はなぜhtmlタグだけなのかと思ったら、flashタグもactionscriptタグもないのですね。

本家ではactionscriptタグよりactionscript-3タグの方が投稿件数が多いので、こちらを採用すべきでしょうか？

- actionscript 累計8394件、今週9件
- actionscript-2(as2) 累計1850件
- actionscript-3(as3) 累計35809件、今週87件

Comment: 英語版の歴史が長いため、ソフトのバージョンアップと同時にタグ付けも更新されます。「as-3が多いから、as-3にしよう」を決断する前に、「当サイトのオーディエンスにとっては、一番わかり易いタグは何ですか？」を考えたらより使いやすくなると思います。

Comment: そうですね、[より質問の文脈を明確にできる](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1641/8000)ので詳細なタグの方が好みではありますが、質問者がバージョンを意識していない場合などを考えると、バージョンなしのタグもあったほうがいいとは思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

タグ追加の権限がもらえたので、とりあえず件の記事には[flash](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash)[actionscript](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionscript)[actionscript-3](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionscript-3)を付けました。